# AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect error while sending email

Tags: java, email, authentication

following code for sending email through our own server gives AuthenticationFailedException

```
String to = "to@abc.co.in";
String from = "from@abc.co.in";
String host = "Mail.abc.co.in";
String message= null;
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
InternetAddress fromAddress = null;
InternetAddress toAddress = null;
try {
  Message simpleMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
  fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
  toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
  simpleMessage.setFrom(fromAddress);
  simpleMessage.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
  simpleMessage.setSubject("-------------");
  simpleMessage.setContent(message, "text/html");
  Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");
  trans.connect("Mail.abc.co.in", 587, "example@abc.co.in", "password");
  trans.sendMessage(simpleMessage, simpleMessage.getAllRecipients());                     
} catch (MessagingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What SMTP server do you use?

TSL/SSL is required in some servers (Google smtp for example)
Try to configure your authorization via ssl.

Here is my version of connecting Google smtp via ssl:

```
private void configSession() throws IOException {

    // Configuring smtp
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", smtpSocketFactoryPort);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", smtpSocketFactoryClass);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", smtpAuth);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);

    session = Session.getInstance(properties, new MailAuthenticator(username, password));
}

private class MailAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    MailAuthenticator(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
}

public void send(){
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email));
        message.setSubject(messageTitle);
        message.setText("Hello");
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error sending email:", e);
    }
```

And the properties:

```
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.port=465
```

Comment: But i have my own mailing server and i want to do mail using that server only.

Comment: @Betty Also I noticed you use default instance of `Session` without `Authentificator`. Better update your question and mention you use your own server